# prove or disprove if $\Gamma,A\models^{v}B$ and $\Gamma,\neg A\models^{v}B$ then $\Gamma\models^{v}B$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

prove or disprove if $\Gamma,A\models^{v}B $ and $\Gamma,\neg A\models^{v}B$ then $\Gamma\models^{v}B$

I believe this is a generalization of the Dichotomy theorem.
The problem I am not quite sure if the same proof will work here.

### Definition:

[image: definition of |=^v]

Comment: What does $\models^v$ mean? The proof depends on the exact definition.

Comment: sorry me I probably confused you, the structure on the left must satisfies the left side without regarding what α is. if so we say that it satisfies the right side, if for any α no matter what α is. What you proved is for t- satisfiability

Comment: @pipeman I am still not completely certain what it $\models^v$ means. Can you give the exact definition of $\models^v$?

Comment: @MarkSaving the formula you've given in the deleted post was exactly the definition.

Comment: @MarkSaving I  added a definition.

Comment: @user953376 can you describe what the relation A is?

Comment: I am not quite sure I get this. let's denote the relation A as R.
and R={1} while the domain is {1,2}
so we have R(x).
Can you explain why $M\models^{v}R(x)$?

@user953376

Comment: the satisfiability depends on if x=1or 2.

Comment: @user953376 you probably meant, t-satisfiability

Comment: @user953376 can you write a full answer? Actually what you might consider is $\Gamma\not\models^v B$ no?

Comment: If A⊨vB,¬A⊨vB are logical truisms. doesn't it mean $\emptyset\models^v B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is false.

Consider a language with constant symbol $c$. Let $x$ be a variable.

Then let $A :\equiv (x = c)$.

Let $B :\equiv \forall x (x = c)$.

Then $A \models^v B$. For suppose $M, c_m \in M$ is a structure and for all $\alpha$, $M, \alpha \models A$. Then consider $m \in M$. Then let $\alpha$ be the variable assignment sending all variables to $m$. Then $M, \alpha \models A$. Then $m = c_m$. So $M = \{c_m\}$. Then clearly $M \models B$.

And $\neg A \models^v B$. For suppose that $M, c_m \in M$ is a structure and for all $\alpha$, $M, \alpha \models \neg A$. Then let $\alpha$ be the variable assignment sending all variables to $c_m$. Then $M, \alpha \models A$. Contradiction. Then $M \models B$.

But it is not the case that $\models^v B$. For we can take the structure $M = \{0, 1\}$, $c_m = 0$. Then $M$ does not model $B$.

Comment: sorry me  I probably confused you, the structure on the left must satisfies the left side without regarding what $\alpha$ is. if so we say that it satisfies the right side, if for any $\alpha$ no matter what $\alpha$ is. What you proved is for t- satisfiability

Comment: @pipeman So you're saying that $\Delta \models^v A$ is defined as $\forall M ((\forall \alpha (M, \alpha \models \Delta)) \implies (\forall \alpha (M, \alpha \models A))$?

Comment: Can I switch $M, \alpha \models A$ to just $M \models A$? 
edit: yes exactly!
@Mark Saving

Comment: @pipeman I believe I have now answered your question. If we allow $A$ to contain a free variable (which you did not disallow), then your statement is false. I have not proved this here, but requiring $A$ to have no free variables makes this statement true.

Comment: The difference for this answer, vs the previous answer is the free variable x. I can put in x whatever I like via the assignment right (as long it is in the domain)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure regarding this:
And ¬A⊨vB. For suppose that M,cm∈M is a structure and for all α, M,α⊨¬A. Then let α be the variable assignment sending all variables to cm. Then M,α⊨A. Contradiction. Then M⊨B.

can you explain, what is the contradiction, and what you proved?

Comment: @pipeman The contradiction is that $M, \alpha \models A$. But we already know that $M, \alpha \models \neg A$. This is a contradiction. So really, it's just never the case that $M \models \neg A$.

Comment: I am not quite sure that this is correct. you showed that the assumption the structure satisfies $¬A$ doesn't hold if it satisfies for $A$. which is trivial, but not helpful.
I believe you've just showed that the same structure doesn't hold for $A$ and $¬A$. But there can be many other structures that do satisfies $¬A$.

Comment: @pipeman According to your definition, $M \models T$ means that $M, \alpha \models T$ for every $\alpha$. It can never be the case that $M, \alpha \models \neg A$ for every $\alpha$.

Comment: But it can be that: $M\models A,Γ;N\models¬A,Γ$ whereas N and M are different structures.

Comment: @pipeman What I'm saying is that for all $M$, it cannot be the case that $M \models \neg A$.

Comment: Yes, what you got is a contradiction, that the same structure M which satisfies $Γ,A$ satisfies $Γ,¬A$. But you haven't shown that for *any* structure you'll get the contradiction , you only showed that the same structure, cannot simultaneously satisfies them both.  the definition requires that for any structure S which satisfies the left side, it will also satisfies the right side. It doesn't require to them all be satisfied by only one structure.

Comment: hmmm you claim that for any structure including N we get a contradiction, let me think about it.